# send message from external html to chrome extension host

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-native-messaging

I am trying to send message from a dummy html page on my desktop directory to chrome extension host using chrome native messaging.

here is my host's json file:

```
{
  "name": "com.myhost",
  "description": "Chrome Native Messaging API Example Host",
  "path": "myhost.exe",
  "type": "stdio",
  "allowed_origins": [
    "chrome-extension://knldjmfmopnpolahpmmgbagdohdnhkik/"
  ]
}
```

this json is registered under Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Google\Chrome\NativeMessagingHosts\com.myhost

here is my extension's manifest.json file:

```
{
  // Extension ID: knldjmfmopnpolahpmmgbagdohdnhkik
  "key": "MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDcBHwzDvyBQ6bDppkIs9MP4ksKqCMyXQ/A52JivHZKh4YO/9vJsT3oaYhSpDCE9RPocOEQvwsHsFReW2nUEc6OLLyoCFFxIb7KkLGsmfakkut/fFdNJYh0xOTbSN8YvLWcqph09XAY2Y/f0AL7vfO1cuCqtkMt8hFrBGWxDdf9CQIDAQAB",
  "name": "Native Messaging Example",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "Send a message to a native application.",
  "app": {
    "launch": {
      "local_path": "main.html"
    }
  },
  "icons": {
    "128": "icon-128.png"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "nativeMessaging","tabs","webNavigation","system.display","*://dummy.html/*"
  ],
"background": {
    "background_page": "background.html" 
  },

  "externally_connectable": {
    "matches": ["*://dummy.html/*"],
    "ids": ["*"]
    },
    "content_scripts" : [{
        "matches" : ["*://*/*"],
        "js" : ["content_script.js"],
        "run_at": "document_end"
    }]
}
```

I am able to send and receive message from main.html page. However, I couldn't send any message from dummy.html file to extension host by using following commands:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage('knldjmfmopnpolahpmmgbagdohdnhkik', { command: 'heyyyy' },
            function(response){

            });
window.postMessage("knldjmfmopnpolahpmmgbagdohdnhkik", { text: "heyyy" });
```

When trying to communicate I get the following errors:

```
Port error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.
Error in event handler for 'undefined': Cannot read property 'message' of undefined       
TypeError: Cannot read property 'message' of undefined
```

any suggestions? 
Thanks

Comment: `"*://dummy.html/*"` defines a web URL, not a file.

Comment: I created a new server and then published dummy.html on this server. I have tried to send message again but nothing changed.

Comment: Uhm, sendMessage connects to your extension, not to the native host, so you need to have chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal in your extension (as shown in the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external-webpage)) where you'll connect to the host via connectNative as shown in the next section of the documentation.

Comment: hi  @wOxxOm when I tried connectNative I get following error: chrome.runtime.connectNative is not a function

Comment: It means you've using it in the wrong place. It should be in a properly declared background script.

Comment: hi @wOxxOm actually I downloaded native host and extension example from chrome website and followed instructions for setup and I found a .net host example. When I open chrome .net host is not running. When I navigate to chrome-extension://extensionid/main.html OR chrome-extension://extensionid/_generated_background_page.html I can see host starts running on task manager. On main.html I can successfully send message to host and receive message from host. My question is I have an another website which has dummy.html file. On that file how can I send/receive message to/from host?

Comment: Web pages can't send directly to the host. I don't know how else to say it. I believe my comments above contain all the info. Note, you may want to write an extension, not an app, in which case the official sample isn't helpful as is - you need to remove the app-specific keys in manifest and declare a background script properly.

Comment: Actually I want to get the windows lock/unlock information and use it on my website. My .NET app listening continuously and when there is any lock/unlock, necessary information passed to the background.js and then I need to pass that info to my website for use it. I need to do some actions  on my website according to the windows lock/unlock event. So I think I need both extension and app.

Comment: When I mentioned ”app” I meant an exact term describing a special kind of an extension that has ”app” key in manifest.json.